# Python: writing combinations of letters and numbers to a file

Tags: python, string, performance, file-io

I have been looking at other SO posts in order to create a program that will generate a list of combinations (letters + numbers) given certain parameters, I have gotten as far as this:

```
from itertools import product
from string import *

keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat =  3)]
file = open("file.txt", "w")

for item in keywords: 
  file.write("%s\n" % item)

file.close()
```

This program works fine if the **repeat** parameter is kept to 3/4, but if raised to 5 or above then the program does not finish - it doesn't crash, just never seems to finish. I am guessing it is a performance issue, however I am not sure. If someone could give a more efficient program it would be most appreciated.

Secondly, I want the program to output both:

- aec
- cea

With this current code, it will only output the first.

Comment: Use permutations from itertools

Comment: It worked for me. Are you sure you closed the file? You need to call `file.close()` not `file.close`.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work for me, any suggestions / reasons? I will try permutations.

Comment: As suggested by @ajcr, you should use `generator` expression here. But the still the program will take lot of time to just write into your file.

Answer (score 7):

`product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat=5)` generates all 916,132,832 possibilities for the strings (`62**5`).

Your current code is making a list of all of these string objects in memory before writing to the file. This might be too much for your system since each three-letter string object will be around 52 bytes (in Python 3, slightly less in Python 2). This means you're making about 44GB of Python strings for your list.

Instead, use a *generator* expression for `keywords` to avoid holding all the strings in memory (just use `(...)` rather than `[...]`):

```
keywords = (''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat=5))
```

You can then iterate and write the strings to a file as before:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in keywords: 
        f.write(item)
        f.write('\n')
```

(also, `product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat=3)` *will* generate both 'aec' and 'cea'.)

Comment: or `f.write(item+'\n')`

Comment: This is a very nice answer (y)

Comment: @IronFist: thanks; that would certainly work too, although `item+'\n'` creates a new string each time (which I'd guess is slightly slower, but I've not timed it yet...).

Comment: @ajcr...forgive my lack of knowledge here..but is it slower than writing twice to `f`?

Comment: @IronFist: it's an interesting point. I just tried timing things and they appeared to be almost exactly the same. If anything, `f.write(item+'\n')` was slightly quicker (Python seems pretty good at concatenation of short strings). I guess either is fine in this case!

Comment: Good to know that..@ajcr

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")
for item in product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat =  3):
  file.write('%s\n' % ''.join(item))
file.close()
```

Here we avoid collecting all of the answers into a big array (keywords). product() returns a generator, so it is more efficient to iterate over it than to collect all of its responses before iterating.